# UISwitch crash on value change IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiswitch

I'm trying to set a simple UISwitch that simply copy is a boolean value (off or on) in a Bool Variable.
The problem is that when I run my app, every time I change the switch value, it crashes with the following error (in the pic). I attach you the code I'm trying to use:

```
import UIKit

class TypeOfDiabetesVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var insulinDSwitch: UISwitch!

    var insulinsSwitchState : Bool = true

// viewDidLoad and Memory warning funcs etc...

@IBAction func insulinDSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if (sender.isOn == true) {
            insulinDSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
        } else {
            insulinDSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
        }
        insulinsSwitchState = sender.isOn
    }
```

The app builds successfully but then when I tap on the switch to toggle it on or off, the app crash:

[link to the image](https://ibb.co/fTZ35J)

Comment: Make sure `UISwitch` IBAction connected properly.

Comment: Remove the action from storyboard and attach it again. The storyboard is trying to call "InsulinDSwitch" but your function is "insulinDSwitch"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method in `TypeOfDiabetesVC` View controller is named `insulinDSwitch` but the storyboard is trying to call `InsulinDSwitch`. The case difference is making the app crash.

**Possible Solution** : Remove the Action from storyboard and connect it again to the right method.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have to admit this was a silly mistake using the wrong name of the outlet.

Comment: Welcome @FabioMagarelli, It happens to the best of us :D

Answer (score 0):

This crash is because you haven't connected the IBAction with storyboard, Please do it again.

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with your outlets please check the outlet of the action you have attached with the `UISwitch`.